# MacScript Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: macos, excel, applescript, vba

In OSX Excel provides functionality to run Applescript code via the `MacScript` keyword.  I am running shell code via this functionality and it generally looks like this:

```
MacScript "do shell script ""/usr/bin/whatever"""
```

recently I decided I wanted to capture the output (and stderr) because the command was failing and I wanted to see what the error was... so I rewrote it like this:

```
MacScript "do shell script ""/usr/bin/whatever > /tmp/out 2>&1"""
```

but I get the error above.  if I run the given command in the AppleScript editor, I get the error:

> The command exited with a non-zero status (number: 1)

so my question is: how do I trap the return code of `MacScript` and prevent Excel from breaking?  I tried:

```
Dim rc As Integer: rc = MacScript(...)
```

but the script still breaks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, to prevent `do shell script` (and therefore, indirectly, `MacScript()`) from throwing an error, make sure that the shell command exits with code `0`.

In your case, to *merely capture the shell command's exit code*, append `; echo $?` to the command string passed to `do shell script`:

Simplified example, using a malformed `date` command:

```
Dim rc As Integer
rc = MacScript("do shell script ""date -nosuchoptions; echo $?""") ' returns 1
```

- `echo $?` outputs the (preceding) command's exit code to *stdout* and is therefore returned by `do shell script`
- as a - desirable - side effect, the exit code will be set to `0`, because the `echo` command succeeds; therefore, the overall command exits with code `0`, thus preventing `do shell script` from throwing an error.

*Caveats*:

- Since you're assigning `MacScript`'s return value to an `Integer` variable, be sure that the `do shell script` command's output can be *parsed as a number*.
  (The above command is safe, as is yours from the question, because the preceding command's stdout output is captured in a file, and the subsequent `echo $?` is guaranteed to output a "number-looking" string.)
- If your shell command is *syntactically* incorrect, `MacScript` will still throw an error; you could use this to distinguish between syntax and runtime errors.

---

If, by contrast, you still want to return a command's *output* and simply know *in the abstract* whether something went wrong:

```
    Dim stdout As String
    On Error Resume Next  ' ignore runtime errors
    stdout = MacScript("do shell script ""date -nosuchoptions""")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Something went wrong.", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "Captured output: " & stdout, vbInformation
    End If
```

- Note that this method does *not* allow you to determine the shell command's *specific* exit code, because Excel VBA translates *any* nonzero shell exit code into the generic error number `5` (`Invalid procedure call or argument`).

---

Finally, you can *combine* the 2 approaches - return the command's output *and* its specific exit code:

```
    Dim stdout As String, rc As Integer, pos As Integer
    ' Execute the command, and appends its exit code as the *last line* of output.
    ' Note how both stdout and stderr output are captured via `2>&1`.
    stdout = MacScript("do shell script ""{ date; date -nosuchoptions; } 2>&1; echo $?""")
    ' Extract the last line from the output captured.
    pos = InStrRev(stdout, Chr$(13)) ' find last line break (\n has been translated to \r by `do shell script`)
    rc = Mid(stdout, pos + 1)        # exit code
    stdout = Left(stdout, pos - 1)   # captured output (only)
    If rc <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Command failed with exit code " & rc & "; captured output: " & stdout, vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Captured output: " & stdout, vbInformation
    End If
```

*Caveats*:

- If your shell command is *syntactically* incorrect, `MacScript` will still throw an error; you could use this to distinguish between syntax and runtime errors.
- If your shell command (the one preceding `echo $?`) doesn't terminate its output with `\n`, parsing out the exit code will not work.

Comment: This was helpful. My problem is that `MacScript` returns a 126, which is "Permission denied" yet the script runs fine in the AppleScript editor. Does VBA require special permissions? (The script file has execute permissions for every group after I did `chmod +x test.sh`)

Comment: @redOctober13: I personally don't know the answer, but I encourage you to ask a _new_ question.